# How to make nice indents at the beginning of each chapter?

Tags: sectioning, indentation, chapters, templates

I'm using [this](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/) template to write my thesis. My chapters look like that:

[image: not_ok]

How can I make latex add the indent in the first paragraph of each section?
[image]

I could manually add a *hspace*, but I'd like to be able to change the template and not to worry about each section seperately. How can I do that?

Comment: probably `\usepackage{indentfirst}` but not indenting the first paragraph is by design and has a long typesetting tradition

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, does the first text look better to you? I know it's by design, but anyway, I don't like it. Do you think I should leave it the way it is?

Comment: I can't guess from your "name" where you are from, but certainly English/American (and I think German) tradition would just use indent as a separator so not have it below a heading. But other language traditions are different. I can't comment on how it looks as there is no heading in the text as shown, so obviously it looks wrong.

Comment: The first text doesn't look better because we don't see the context: it would be different, in my opinion, if there were a title above the first paragraph.

Comment: From the Oxford Style Manual: "It is common not to indent the first paragraph in each chapter" and from Bringhurst: "The simplest way of beginning any block of prose is to start from the margin, flush left, as this paragraph does". With any document, it's a matter of who are you expecting/hoping will read it and will it bother them? On all the creative writing courses I've attended, a first paragraph indent gets flagged as an error (as it's considered an error by literary agents and publishers). You may prefer a first paragraph indent, but it's likely to make your work look unprofessional.

Comment: You could go classical and use lettrine.